# onKeyDown() functionality issue

Tags: android

I was trying to override the back button functionality where I wanted to call the default functionality in case a boolean is set false

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean temp = false;
        if (event.KEYCODE_BACK == keyCode) {
            System.out.println("Back pressed");
            if (isTrue) {
                //Do something
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now this doesn't exactly work how the documentation states. the `//Do Something` part is executed well, but when `isTrue` is `false` i want the default back functionality which is not happening. Im using SDK 1.5

Now,

1. How do I fix this?
2. Is this issue fixed in later SDK updates? If not can someone raise a bug for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want the default behavior, chain to the superclass:

   return(super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
2. The bug is in your code. Also, for Android 1.6 and newer, you are better served overriding the dedicated `onBackPressed()` method (where, again, if you want the default behavior, chain to the superclass).

Comment: Also, you should consider reading this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Comment: Thanks commonsware. I was actually following the documentation as is and it mentioned returning false would work. 
Also thanks ( to Samuh as well) for pointing out the changes for vr1.6 but as per the requirements I have to stick with vr1.5 for now.

Comment: I can see where you might interpret it that way -- it's not written terribly well -- but the documentation does not say what you think it does.